# I am trying to determine what is the best way to determine what a word means?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to determine what is the best way to determine what a word means?

I found three references and each give a different definition.  For example for **immemorial**, it could mean "centuries ago" or "beyond memory".

Is there a goto online reference that is best.  The 3 I found are below.

For example authors love to say "Since time immemorial ..."

**REFERENCE**

dictionary.com

collinsdictionary.com

merriam-webster.com

Comment: words are made up and mean whatever you want them to mean. but if you want someone to tell you what they mean, i see what you mean

Comment: Can I say, "since coffee immemorial" ... for example, what would that mean?

Comment: Look up actual examples of sentences where "immemorial" is used to better understand it's meaning and usage. I recommend Oxford Online Dictionaries.

Comment: "Since coffee immemorial people have enjoyed a scone pairing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Immemorial' always appears as "time immemorial." The old-fashioned printers' term is a *cliché,* a group of words always clustered in the same group so that it saved time to stick the letters together.

The answer is to feed the cliché into the search box: "For time immemorial" gives three answers immediately on my browser. "Time immemorial" gives even more including a Law Dictionary:

**What is TIME IMMEMORIAL? Black's Law Dictionary**
 which explains the meaning and background [Black's Law Dictionary](https://thelawdictionary.org/time-immemorial/).

Comment: The answer is before 1189.  Law don't go round here mr. law dog.

Comment: If I was a law dog, I'd be rich. I'm a collector of out-of-date knowledge. But anyway, it worked didn't it? You got a quick answer from the search engine instead of three different dictionaries